# "is now a special repository: its README.md will appear on your profile!" but it doesn't work

Tags: github, markdown

I want to change a default page of my Profile on github. I create a folder with the same name with my id-user (https://github.com/HAKO411/HAKO411) and It appears a line as: "HAKO411/HAKO411 is now a special repository: its README.md will appear on your profile!". However, my profile didn't change. Do you know how to fix it?

Updated solution: The problem is the initial Repositories is made with a different name then I rename to "HAKO411" --> not working

So I did: - Delete that repositories - Create a new repositories with exact name of my id-user - Upload again --> it works.

Comment: When I click the link, the page returns a 404 not found

Comment: Now it is back and it seems to work, does it work for you?

Comment: Looks like it works now, did you by any chance make it a private repo?

Comment: @jessehouwing As I know so far, you have to make it public.

Answer (score 1):

Updated solution:
The problem is the initial Repositories is made with a different name then I rename to "HAKO411" --> not working

So I did:
- Delete that repositories
- Create a new repositories with exact name of my id-user
- Upload again
--> it works.